# How do I get the content header from my POST?

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get the content header query string returned. I'm getting a response but it does not include the query string I am trying to pass. I'm running on an Apache server.

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'feed_them_social' => 'yes',
        'refresh_token'    => get_option( 'custom_refresh_token' ),
        'time'             => esc_html( get_option( 'custom_token_exp_time' ) ),
        )
);
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$command = 'curl --data "' . $context . '" https://my-url.com';
exec($command, $token);
$output    = implode('', $token);
print_r( $output );
```

Below is the response I'm getting.

```
Content-Length: 15
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: */*
Host: youtube-token-refresh.myurl.com
User-Agent: curl/7.77.0
```

I added this to php file on the server I am trying to get a response from. I just want to print out the header content with my query string for now but not having any luck. What am I missing?

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();

foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
   echo "$header: $value <br />\n";
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling cURL from the command line instead of using PHP's cURL? Then it will be _much_ easer to get all the info you want in PHP. `apache_request_headers()` will return the request headers on the request to your PHP file and has nothing to do with any request your code are making. Also, you seem to be asking for the _response_ headers, not _request_ headers.

Comment: Thanks for making me think! I found my solution by converting the exec code to php's cURL. https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/

Answer (score 0):

Using `exec` is not secure and also it's a hard way to use `curl`.

In this case, I suggest `file_get_contents` function that works fine with `stream_context_create`. More Information: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Just replace the last 4 lines with the following code.

```
$output = file_get_contents('https://my-url.com', false, $context);
print_r($output);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! You are correct file_get_contents does work. I was looking for a cURL method in this instance though. I found a solution by converting my exec call to php cURL. This is an amazing tool to convert https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/